# $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} (x^2+y^2)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2+x^2+y}\right)$ does not exist.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to prove this limit does not exist. I already tried to change to polar coordinates and got $\lim_{r \to 0} r^2\tan\left( \dfrac{\pi}{2+r^2\cos^2\theta+r\sin\theta}\right)$, which I tried to evaluate the limit by L'Hôpital, but lost myself on huge calculations - probably not the best way.

Also I tried to evaluate the limit along the lines $y=0, y=x, y = x^2, y = \sqrt{x}$ and all of them lead me to limits where I have to use L'Hôpital several times - probably not the best way either.

How can I prove this limit doesn't exist?

Thanks.

Comment: p.s: I understand that I need to show two paths where the limits are different, this is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Try fixing $\theta=\pm\pi/2 $ separately and then send $r\to 0$. You should see that you get different limits. To check your own understanding, try to figure out why $\theta=\pm\pi/2$ works. Hint: they both send $\cos$ to zero, but changes the sign of $\sin$.

Comment: Also try setting : $y=ax^2$ and prove the limit depends on $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate the limits along the axes.  If $y = 0$, then $$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x,0) = \lim_{x \to 0}x^2 \tan \frac{\pi}{2 + x^2} = \lim_{u \to 0^+} u \tan \frac{\pi}{2 + u},$$ which we can calculate either via L'Hopital or by series expansion (I leave this as an exercise).  The result is $4/\pi$.  However, $$\lim_{y \to 0} f(0,y) = \lim_{y \to 0} y^2 \tan \frac{\pi}{2 + y} = 0,$$ since the previous limit was finite and nonzero.